# How to get Message Id for Mailinator public inbox with curl command

Tags: java, mailinator

I have been trying with curl command to get the message id for public account in mailinator.

But i think there is some issue, as i am getting the html response, and no details are there for inbox messages. I am not sure what wrong i am doing, none of the below command has worked.

```
curl -x GET https://www.mailinator.com/v3/inbox.jsp?to=test11 -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -H 'Accept: application/json'



curl -x GET "https://mailinator.com/api/v3/domains/public/inboxes.jsp?to=test11"
```

Gone through mailinator apis, but clear information is not there, also wathed few youtube videos still unable to find any relevant information. Tried with below command and java code.

`curl -x GET "https://mailinator.com/api/v2/domains/public/inboxes.jsp?to=test11"

curl -x GET "https://mailinator.com/ws/fetchpublic/api/v3/domains/public/inboxes.jsp?to=test11"`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MailinatorPublicAccountExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String publicAccount = "test11";

        try {
            // Create the API URL
            String apiUrl = String.format("https://www.mailinator.com/v3/inbox.jsp?to=%s", publicAccount);

            // Send GET request to the API
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // Get the API response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();

            // Process the response
            JSONArray messages = new JSONArray(response.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject message = messages.getJSONObject(i);
                String messageId = message.getString("id");
                String messageBody = fetchMessageBody(messageId);

                System.out.println("Message ID: " + messageId);
                System.out.println("Message Body: " + messageBody);
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            }

            // Close the connection
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String fetchMessageBody(String messageId) throws IOException {
        // Create the API URL for fetching message body
        String apiUrl = String.format("https://api.mailinator.com/v3/domains/mailinator.com/messages/%s/body", messageId);

        // Send GET request to the API
        URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // Get the API response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        // Close the connection
        connection.disconnect();

        return response.toString();
    }
}
```